Can a 20A circuit mix 15A and 20A receptacles, when a 20A is intended for occassional space heater use?
Two new 20A circuit was run to service a new office / rec room in a basement. There's 5 receptacles on each of them. The receptacles installed are 15A tamper resistant. On each of the circuits, one of those receptacles might be used for a space heater on occasion. Doesn't need to be a heavy duty or hard-wired one necessarily, a 1500W personal space heater would suffice and even those can run 1300W. Still, it seems prudent to have a 20A receptacle, on a 20A circuit, when any kind of electrical heating like this is a use case?
For that reason I'm thinking one of the 15A receptacles should be replaced with a 20A receptacle. The horizontal-slot in the 20A receptacle isn't needed since most space heaters I've seen have a 15A-style plug, but that horizontal would show which receptacle is rated for 20A use.
I know it's okay for 15A receptacles to be on a 20A circuit, and that's been answered thoroughly here before. But is it okay to mix a 20A receptacle in with mostly 15A receptacles on a 20A circuit?

Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12763/why-is-it-safe-to-use-15-a-receptacles-on-a-20-a-circuit

TL;DR 15A receptacles are all you need. Just get good ones.
This is already handled very well in code. With most circuit sizes, the receptacle type must exactly match the circuit size. For example, you can only have 15A receptacles on a 15A circuit. However, you are allowed to have 15A receptacles on a 20A circuit provided there are at least 2 receptacles on the circuit. That can be as little as a standard 15A duplex receptacle - while that is one "device" it counts as the 2 receptacles it actually contains when it comes to this particular rule. You can have 1 or more 20A, 2 or more 15A, or any combination of 15A and 20A.
The basic problem is a Catch-22: So many houses have had only 15A circuits/receptacles for so long that manufacturers of 120V plug-in consumer-grade appliances simply don't manufacture much that requires a 20A circuit because that would severely limit market share. And the cycle continues - people don't install 20A receptacles (since they don't have to) because they have nothing to plug into them except 15A appliances.
However, the 20A circuits are still useful. They are required for new circuits in bathrooms and kitchens and certain other places, not because of a great need for 20A appliances - we already established that's not the case - but because it allows multiple appliances without overloading circuits. Or at least with a lower chance of overloading circuits. Two examples:

1875W hair dryer + other stuff. On a 15A circuit that would be the limit. Which means that if you add even a little bit extra - lights, fan, electric shaver, etc. you start to go over 15A and risk problems. With a 20A circuit you have an extra 5A to work with and you are fine unless you plug in two hair dryers, or a hair dryer and curling iron, at the same time.
1500W space heaters. I hate these things with a passion. But sometimes they are a necessary evil, particularly if your furnace dies on a cold day. They are limited to 12A because they can run for a long time (unlike a hair dryer), which is why they are pretty much all 1500W. If you run 2 of them on a 15A circuit then that's 24A and you're going to (hopefully) trip the breaker very quickly - and if you don't then the 14 AWG wire will overheat. If you run 2 of then on a 20A circuit then you have a little breathing room. You will probably trip the breaker eventually but a few minutes of running them probably won't and it is definitely safer. (But please, if you plan to use multiple space heaters run multiple circuits.)

We've established that 15A receptacles are allowed on a 20A circuit and that they can be useful on a 20A circuit. So that just leaves the receptacles themselves. Because of this rule allowing them on a 20A circuit, they are actually designed to allow 20A to pass through the device. There really is no functional difference other than the extra slot to allow 20A plugs to fit.
If you want some extra safety, stick with 15A receptacles but go to better quality receptacles. Basically instead of the (current Home Depot pricing, but while the prices will change the concept will likely exist for a long time) $ 1.50 residential grade 15A tamper-resistant duplex receptacle, go for the $ 3.42 commercial grade 15A tamper-resistant duplex receptacle. For the extra money you get "screw to clamp" instead of "backstab", self-grounding (saves a connection if you are using metal boxes) and a much more rugged/long-lasting design.

Thanks, this resolves my main misunderstanding, which is that 15A receptacles are actually designed for 20A to pass through the device. I didn't realize that, which is why I thought a 20A receptacle was needed.

Up to share/point me toward info on why you despise 1500W electric heaters so much? I have a lot of old hardwired baseboard which seems similar in benefits and badness. For this area in question, a wood stove would serve it for extended use, and being a basement it doesn't need much heat. But for shorter-term warm ups, there are two 20A circuits, and I figure one receptacle on each could run a 1500W heater to get the area warm short-term.

Ignoring energy efficiency - which is a hard thing to deal with because the way you get more efficient costs a lot more (heat pumps, basically) so just doesn't pay for a lot of situations, my main issue is safety. The old hardwired baseboard heaters, Cadet in-wall heaters, etc. are very safe. Plug-in space heaters are very unsafe. Key safety issues: tripping hazard of cords, overloading of surge protectors/outlet strips (because people do that - won't trip the breaker but can easily melt the cheap outlet strips), extension cords (because the receptacle you should use is behind a big

piece of furniture so you use a 16 AWG/13A rated extension cord and melt it; tip-over hazards; fire hazard from stuff on or next to the space heater (can happen with built-ins but much less likely IMHO) and much more.

So hardwired permanently installed heaters and plug-in space heaters are similar in benefits (heat a small area reasonably well and with a low cost to install, though obviously even lower for plug-in than hardwired) but very, very, very different in "badness".

Thanks for that. Makes me feel better about the hardwired heaters, especially if a child-safe cover/grate is in front of them. The 1500W portable ones I use have tip-over protections and I am careful about those other hazards...good to know I'm thinking of the same reasons you're wary of them.

The biggest issue I see/have with space heaters is they are only 100% efficient.  I believe natural gas is 250%, and heat pumps can be between 300 and 500% depending on how cold it gets and for how long.  Depending on your climate and cost per KWH , your electric bill could exceed 500/month in the winter.

@cybernard: Natural gas furnaces consume a modest amount of electrical energy and a much larger amount of chemical energy.  They can only exceed 100% efficiency if one views the chemical energy as "free".

Natural gas in a modern furnace is 90 to 95 % efficent. In terms of end user cost that's on the order of 250% compared to resistance electrical. But it varies widely depending on local market factors.

On a 20A circuit with at least two outlets you can mix 15A and 20A outlets any way you want.  All 15, all 20, or any mix.
There is no point putting a 20A (5-20) receptacle in the circuit if you have no appliances with a 20A plug.  It accomplishes nothing.  They are not better, they can both be purchased at various levels of quality.  If you buy a 15A and 20A outlet of the same make and construction, the 20A one is capable of accepting a 5-20 plug, and the 15A one is capable of preventing that. That's the only difference.
If you think you might buy an appliance with a 20A plug you need to give more thought to what is practical and manageable, rather than what is allowed. If you are provisioning for a (probably) 1920W heater with a 20A socket for it, it should probably be the only outlet on the circuit, unless you plan it purposefully, EG, the only other outlet is for something that would not be used at the same time, like a window air conditioner.   Don't install new outlets that, from the start, will require end-users to dance around the circuit capacity.
.

Also good luck finding a 120V heater that requires a 20A circuit.  I won't say they don't exist, but I spent 20 seconds on the internet and couldn't find one.  :) So long as you're wiring up a socket just for a big heater, go with 240V where the selection is enormous.  It's a whole different rant but I wish the 5-20 was depracated. It's only used for some high end espresso machines, low-end phone-booth style saunas, and some air conditioners from the 1970s.

And some "occasional use" EVSE, I've found.  Recently I sold my house and moved into a rental.  Having not installed my 240V EVSE in the new house yet, I figured I'd dig out the "occasional use" one that came with the car to top it up.  Pulled it out of the car, unrolled the cord and BAM - 5-20.  Luckily, I've found NEMA 5-20 receptacles to be reasonably common in garages in CA that also have the laundry inside.

@ChrisO it's actually a good use case.  If your garage outlets are all 15A ones on a 20A circuit, and you don't have Supercharger Envy,  you can swap an outlet for $5 and get a 30% jump in charging speed without opening the breaker panel or drilling a single hole.
